# Is there a way to be able to conclusively detect/find a cellphone signal jammer?

Tags: signal, cellphone

I hope this is the right place to ask this. I'm going through a dispute with my employer and I'm being threatened with termination (we are both preparing for a legal battle). A day later I get no cellphone reception in my cubicle when I always had decent signal. I'm suspecting that my employer is jamming the signal (which I understand is a federal crime). Is there a way I can find this or conclusively find out that signals are being jammed? i.e. will a phone behave in certain way near a signal jammer? Or will it just act like there is no coverage. Data has always been a bit slow in my office but I've never had issues with talk or text. Right now everything is completely off. I can't even get a text-message on telegram through on the data.

It seems far fetched since it's such a stupid thing to do, given that it's a federal crime. But the timing is just really off. Also, this new blind-spot seems to be centered around my cubicle.

Comment: Reminds me of [radar-detector-detector-detectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_detector#Radar_detector_detectors)

Comment: It may not be a federal crime in your own premises as long as the range of the jammer does not exceed your property boundary. See...http://www.idigitaltimes.com/new-pepper-grinder-blocks-all-electronics-during-meals-while-grinding-spice-your-food-428558

Comment: Discussion on MeFi: http://ask.metafilter.com/141006/How-can-I-find-out-if-my-employer-is-using-a-cell-phone-jamming-device Available products: http://www.jammer4uk.com/jammer-detectors-c-3.html (surprisingly cheap)

Comment: @Trevor on the other hand doing it on commercial premises probably is http://edition.cnn.com/2014/10/03/travel/marriott-fcc-wi-fi-fine/ - also, you may be able to do useful detection with one of those $10 SDR devices if you can work the software

Comment: You could always try walking away from your desk in three of four different directions till you get bars, Then map out the area. You should be able to locate the centre of that.

Comment: Ha @pjc50 .. That one falls into the bottomless legal pit of "Is a hotel building public or private..." Good find though :)

Comment: If the boss (or a supporter) is truly jamming your cell phone, they wouldn't want to disturb other worker's communications.  So the signal jummer is probably quite low-power and localized.  That being said, look behind your desk, under your chair, in any potted plants you have, etc, and see if you find anything...

Comment: I'll look more thoroughly when I go back. I think the perfect place to hide it would be above one of the ceiling tiles above my cubicle. There's no way for me to check it discretely.

Comment: http://osmocom.org/projects/sdr/wiki/rtl-sdr get a cheap SDR, that cover all the frequency band of interest. At first view a Elonics E4000 could be the one.